# Reverse proxy multiple local servers under subdirectories of web server?

Tags: nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, ngrok

I have multiple HTTP servers running on multiple machines within a LAN:

- server1: 192.168.1.2:80
- server2: 192.168.1.4:8000

I have no control over the page structure or content. The pages have relative links and scripts (JS) that dynamically load other pages in the server.

The goal is to create a single web server that exposes these local servers to the web like so:

- server1: https://website.com/server1/
- server2: https://website.com/server2/

The structure of each server should appear to have moved under /server on the web server. What's a simple way to do this? I'm trying to avoid writing custom server logic.

I've tried nginx's proxy_pass but this doesn't work for relative links:

```
server {
    listen 8001;
    
    location ~ ^/server1/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.9:80/$1;
    }
    
    location ~ ^/server2/(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.12:80/$1;
    }
}
```

I've tried looking at the Referer header and redirecting to the correct subdirectory but HTTP 3xx is not correctly handled by the JS in the local servers. ([ref](https://newbedev.com/nginx-redirect-via-proxy-rewrite-and-preserve-url))

[alias](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) is not an option as the URL structure of the local servers may overlap with each other.

Port forwarding is a no-go as I don't have access to the router.

PS. Maybe relevant, but the machine hosting the web server does not have a public IP. I am exposing it via an [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) tunnel.